# How to change service restriction policy Security Level using commandline

Tags: batch, group-policy

Are you able to change service restriction policy security level using the command line or a batch/reg script, I have LGPO how ever i'm not sure how to use it.
My goal is to have a batchfile to change the security leve. Any input is helpful.

Comment: I’m not sure that the Salt River Project is on-topic here.   If you are talking about some other SRP, please say so, because “Salt River Project” is the top result for “SRP” from Google.

Comment: service restriction policy ***